# Need a startup script in windows to send ALT+F11 keys?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

We are using a shared desktop on thin clients. By default it comes with windowed screen, but by pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> keys it will restore to full screen. So, we want a script to execute at Windows log-on with some delay.

Comment: [Before You Ask](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#before)

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully a login vbscript will work for you.  Either append this to an existing login script or save it as a ".vbs" file.  [Microsoft has some good tutorials if you are unfamiliar with login scripts.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784088%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 'Create wshell object
WScript.Sleep(5000) 'Lets wait 5 seconds

WshShell.AppActivate "EXACT TITLE OF THE WINDOW YOU WANT" 'EDIT THIS LINE!
'The line above selects the window so we make sure the keystrokes are sent to it

WshShell.SendKeys "%{F11}" 'Send ALT+F11
Wscript.Quit 'Quit the script
```